# Toggle class depending on the div

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do you toggle a class on a div element depending on where the user is on the screen.

Eg- If the user scrolls past a div block with the class '.dark', an active class '.active' should be toggled on the header element.

I have the following code that works with a single instance of '.dark'.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var hieghtThreshold = $(".dark").offset().top;
var hieghtThreshold_end  = $(".dark").offset().top +$(".dark").height() ;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= hieghtThreshold && scroll <=  hieghtThreshold_end ) {
            $('header').removeClass('active');
        }
        else {
            $('header').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

However this will only work with one. What I'm trying to achieve is multiple '.dark' classes on the page.

Comment: i've done other times, somethng like this, and this is the logic i've used

Comment: if you have multiple `.dark` use `.each()` and get the offset individually

Comment: Hi @Satpal, I thought the same but it seems to only be picking up the last instance of .dark

Comment: `It only picks up on the second instance of .dark it seems?`  and `it seems to only be picking up the last instance of .dark`-> these are two different things. Please clarify it

Comment: @AlivetoDie Sorry, got mixed up there. I have two .dark elements. The class does NOT respond when the user scrolls past the first .dark